# Powershell - Conditionally add parameter/argument to cmdlet

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

Suppose I have a Powershell script similar to this:

```
$par = [...]
New-Connection `
  -Server $par.Server `
  -User $par.User `
  -Pwd $par.Pwd `
  - [...]
```

If `$par.Pwd` is empty or null, `New-Connection` will throw an error.

So, I only want to include this parameter, if `$par.Pwd` has a value. Since there are a lot(!) of parameters, which might be empty, I don't want to write the command in 1000 different variations. I thought of sth like.

```
New-Connection `
  -Server $par.Server `
  -User $par.User `
  $(if ($par.Pwd) {-Pwd $par.Pwd})
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about using the hashtable approach to creating new objects:

```
$Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
    Name             = $obj.Name 
    OptValue1        = $obj.OptValue1
    OptValue2        = $obj.OptValue2   
    OptValue3        = $null
    OptValue4        = "MyValue"
}  
$Object
```

**Update**
Splatting may also help, see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx) for more details, but if all your parameter names match you might be able to call New-Connection then pass it a hashtable containing your values.

```
New-Connection @par
```

Comment: Splatting is definitely the answer he needs.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad, that this is a PS 2.0 feature though. Good to know however, maybe I can use it some time in the future.

Comment: Is this possible with params that don't have a value (eg: `-WhatIf`) or for params that don't have a name (eg: passing a filename to `Remove-Item`) ?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Yes. *All* parameters have names. And switches are basically bools. You can use: `@{Path = "*"; WhatIf = $true}`

Comment: @DavidMartin Where is the use of condition here. I tried with adding a condition inside a splatter, but didn't work.
Like `$par = @{ If ( $SomeVar -eq $True) { 'Param1' = $Obj.option1 } }`

Comment: @AniketGM Create the object first, then conditionally add properties